# Validation Rule to Make Sure Time Window Doesn't Fall Between Two Date/Time fields

Tags: validation-rule

Is there an easier/better way to do this? There doesn't appear to be an easy date/time between functions. I tried the following conditions, but I am having issues with the condition of the start occurring <> Friday and Ending <> Friday Window.

I was going to try a Day + hours condition, to then see if that ends up on Friday in the window, but it seems complicated and hoping someone has a better suggestion.

Suggestions appreciated

```
AND(
  /* General Requirements  */ 
  Owner:Queue.QueueName = "TESTING",

  /* Conditional */ 
    OR(
        /* If on Friday during the blackout  */ 

        AND(
            /* Starts during blackout */ 
            WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(Start_Time__c)) =  6,
            (Hour( TIMEVALUE(Start_Time__c))  >= 12),
            (Hour( TIMEVALUE(Start_Time__c))  <= 19)
        ),        


        AND(
            /* Ends during blackout  */
            WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(End_Time__c)) =  6, 
            (Hour( TIMEVALUE(End_Time__c))  >= 12),
            (Hour( TIMEVALUE(End_Time__c))  <= 19)
        ),

        AND(
            /* Froday Starts Before & Ends After */ 
            IF(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(Start_Time__c)) <= 6 && (Hour( TIMEVALUE(Start_Time__c))  < 12),true, false),
            IF(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(End_Time__c))   >= 6 && (Hour( TIMEVALUE(End_Time__c))    > 19),true, false)
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: You appear not to be aware of WEEKDAY, nor the idea of factoring out common parts of logic expressions. More you do not appear to be aware that interval overlaps can be tested using `startA < finishB && finishA >= startB`.

Comment: I was unaware of the weekday function, which is more concise than using the Case to determine it.
As for the interval overlaps, the only one presenting an issue is the issue I'm trying to account for the Start/stop which is greater than the desired window of time on the specified day of the week.

Comment: I would highly recommend looking at a this badge: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas also checking all date and time functions from this site https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5